# how to set complete site background to a color or image?

Tags: theming

I used this:

## wrapper    { background-color:yellow; }

but I want really everything in the background to get colored. how to?

Code above just makes the wrapper background change.

Comment: Questions regarding pure CSS should really be on the main [se] site.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying same for body tag !

body {
      background: yellow;
    }